# TypeError when importing ghostscript on Python

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes, ghostscript

I have installed ghostscript on my machine and is located at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.20
```

and installed the python module via pip

```
pip install ghostscript
```

however when I try and import ghostscript I get this error

```
>>> import ghostscript
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import ghostscript
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ghostscript\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import _gsprint as gs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ghostscript\_gsprint.py", line 281, in <module>
    libgs = windll.LoadLibrary(libgs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 440, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)    
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be string, not Unicode
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? This looks like a bug in Python 2.7.13 (http://bugs.python.org/issue29082). Try upgrading to the latest release of 2.7.

Comment: I am using v2.7.13 so I will upgrade now and see if that fixes it

Comment: The python website says that v2.7.13 is the latest release

Comment: Indeed, that is the latest. Although it looks like you may be able to go back a version to work around this! http://stackoverflow.com/a/41655617/245915

Comment: Downgrading to version 12 fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ghost script was not working in python v2.7.13 so running an installation of v2.7.12 and importing via v2.7.12 imports with no errors